# Get new Bitmap of scaled and visible image

Tags: android, image, view

I'm currently about to display an image in my custom view:

```
public class CustomImageView extends View
```

To arrange the picture the user has the opportunity to set a key to *fullscreen*. The image is now scaled to the width and height of the display, maintaining the aspect ratio:

[image: Scaled Image]

In order of the scaling process the image is wider than the display (in most of the cases). Now the user can set *focal points*: A coordinate which has to be displayed as centered as possible. In case of picture 1 the focal points are x: 50% and y: 50% --> The image is centered. This is reached through

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (bitmapDrawable != null) {
        bitmapDrawable.setBounds(bounds);
        bitmapDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

The *bounds* contain the values of the scaled edges.

Now the tricky part:

I want to add padding to the scaled image, but that ends in another scaling process of the already scaled image:

[image: Padding Image]

Image 2 shows the undesired effect. The image is shrinked again, no way to add left or right padding in this case.

But what I want to display is shown in the next picture:

[image: Padding Image]

I tried to get only the visible part of the scaled image via `getDrawingCache()`. The returned *Bitmap* in fact isn't null, but it neither takes effect.

I thought about an overlay to create the padding, but that would cut parts of the image that should be displayed.

The best way would be to get the scaled and visible image in a new *Bitmap* or *BitmapDrawable*, but I found no successful operation..

**EDIT:**

To make it a little bit more understandable, I made another drawing for you:

[image: Padding Image]

Comment: there is no "scaled image" when using BitmapDrawable

Comment: "I want to add padding to the ..." so use `View#setPadding(int, int, int, int)`

Comment: @pskink if it was that easy i wouldn't have asked for a solution, but 'setPadding' has no effect

Comment: `ImageView#setPadding` has no effect? how come?

Comment: that's the question.. What I want to accomplish is to extract a specific area of the scaled _BitmapDrawable_ to a new _Bitmap/BitmapDrawable_, but `BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()` only returns the original and unscaled image and `getDrawingCache()` has no effect..

Comment: then use scaleType = matrix

Comment: i think we're talking about different things.. i added another picture, i hope that makes the demand a little bit easier to understand

Comment: ok i missed the fact that you are using custom View, not ImageView... but still its unclear whats wrong in that minimalistic approach: http://codeshare.io/5Wjhu ? what do you need "scaled image extract" for???